# Laravel 5.4 RedirectTo not working in ResetPasswordController

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5.4, reset-password

When a user resets their password they are sent to my dashboard. I need to direct them elsewhere and from what I've read I simply add RedirectTo in my ResetPasswordController, but doing so has no effect:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
   use ResetsPasswords;

   protected $redirectTo = '/checkcart';

  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->middleware('guest');
  }
}
```

**UPDATE to provide info on routes which are default auth routes**

The check cart route:

```
Route::get('checkcart', 'CartController@checkcart');
```

The password reset route is determined by

```
Route::auth();
```

which has the default:

```
public function auth()
    {
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

This is the default code and you just have to change "$redirectTo= '/home' to your desired route - "$redirectTo = '/checkcart'

I will need more information like how the route is defined to detect the issue if yet unsolved